# Does it cost rep to downvote a community wiki post?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, community-wiki

I wouldn't be surprised if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I know that you don't gain or lose rep for questions or answers that you set to community wiki.  But does it cost you rep to downvote someone else's cw post?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## No.

> Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation.

Source: [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741)

Answer (score 16):

No, it does not cost reputation to downvote such posts.