# Why my downvotes sometimes don't cost me the expected -1

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvotes on questions be “free”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free)

I've seen this several times, I downvote a post (question or answer) and *my* reputation is *not* decreased by `-1`.

For example I clearly downvoted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703421/installing-an-updated-dcu-file-into-delphi), yet my reputation didn't get the -1 penalty. I invoked a rep recalc before posting the question to be sure. What's up?

Comment: Downvotes on *questions* are free (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free) for details), but answers still cost you 1 point.

Comment: Also, downvotes on community wiki posts (including answers) [are free](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41313/does-it-cost-rep-to-downvote-a-community-wiki-post). That might explain why you occasionally see your rep not decreasing for downvoting answers, too.

Comment: @Cosmin - With enough downvotes an answer is often deleted and you get your point back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

```
question is voted down   -2 
answer is voted down     -2  (-1 to voter)
```

see https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/ for announcement and explanation.